# PBKDF2 Password Hashing for PHP

Tags: php, hash, pbkdf2

Thanks to some great advice on a recent post I'm implementing PBKDF2 from
https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm into a small PHP image gallery I'm building to teach myself some PHP.

I understand that you store the salt and the hash in the database and then reconstruct them to match when the user enters their password. What I don't understand is how the validate_password function on the above website works when it generates a different, unique salt for the same password.

For example, I created a test repeatedly generating a password of just my name (andrew). Each time the final hash was different, presumably due to the salt being unique? However, it did not matter which generated hash I compared the password too, it validated it. (It obviously didn't validate a totally different password like Andrew56 or ndrew1).

Can anyone explain to my simple self why this is the case? It seems like I don't even need to store the salt? I hope this isn't off topic.

```
<?php
/*
 * Password hashing with PBKDF2.
 * Author: havoc AT defuse.ca
 * www: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm
 */

// These constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

function create_hash($password)
{
// format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
$salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" . 
    base64_encode(pbkdf2(
        PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
        $password,
        $salt,
        PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
        PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES,
        true
    ));
}

function validate_password($password, $good_hash)
{
$params = explode(":", $good_hash);
if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
   return false; 
$pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
return slow_equals(
    $pbkdf2,
    pbkdf2(
        $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
        $password,
        $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
        (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
        strlen($pbkdf2),
        true
    )
);
}

// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
$diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
{
    $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
}
return $diff === 0; 
}

/*
 * PBKDF2 key derivation function as defined by RSA's PKCS #5:         https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt
 * $algorithm - The hash algorithm to use. Recommended: SHA256
 * $password - The password.
 * $salt - A salt that is unique to the password.
 * $count - Iteration count. Higher is better, but slower. Recommended: At least 1000.
 * $key_length - The length of the derived key in bytes.
 * $raw_output - If true, the key is returned in raw binary format. Hex encoded otherwise.
 * Returns: A $key_length-byte key derived from the password and salt.
 *
 * Test vectors can be found here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt
 *
 * This implementation of PBKDF2 was originally created by https://defuse.ca
 * With improvements by http://www.variations-of-shadow.com
 */
function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
$algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
    die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
    die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');

$hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
$block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

$output = "";
for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
    // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
    $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
    // first iteration
    $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
    // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
    for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
    }
    $output .= $xorsum;
}

if($raw_output)
    return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
else
    return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
?>
```

Comment: The salt is included in the hash along with other parameters. The validation function extracts that salt and rehashes the password using the same parameters, which should yield the same hash.

Comment: Ah OK @NullUserException thanks. I see now I just store the whole big string that comes out and I don't need to break it down and store it seperately. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for a PBKDF2 implementation for an older PHP version. For anyone else happening to hit this page, if you're using this method directly:

```
pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
```

Then, it does NOT include the salt with the output string, just the hash, which is what I was desiring.

The `create_hash` method is what the Original Poster was using and, with his settings above, that would return:

```
sha256:1000:$salt:$hash
```

This allows you to save it all in one db column, which is easy to use.  However, I would note that you "might" still want to split it up if you care about storage space.  With a hexidecimal salt and password, you can reduce the storage space it takes in half by storing it in a binary column...e.g. in MySQL this is done with `SET binaryColumn=UNHEX('0F0F')`, and then `SELECT HEX(binaryColumn) AS binaryColumn`.  It's more work, so it comes down to your own preference and goals, but thought I'd throw it out there.